# ¿Cómo convertir este array en otro array?

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
$data = array(
    "title" => array(
        "en" => "Title",
        "es" => "Titulo"),
    "description" => array(
        "en" => "Description",
        "es" => "Descripcion")
);
```

Y quiero convertirlo a:

```
$data = array(
    "en" => array(
        "title" => "Title",
        "description" => "Description"),
    "es" => array(
        "title" => "Titulo",
        "description" => "Descripcion")
);
```

Comment: Ya tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta pero no se porque la tienen puesta en espera todavía.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con el siguiente codigo:

```
$data = array(
    "title" => array(
        "en" => "Title",
        "es" => "Titulo"),
    "description" => array(
        "en" => "Description",
        "es" => "Descripcion")
);
//Obtengo los idiomas para ponerlos como llaves en el arreglo nuevo
$keys = array_keys($data[array_keys($data)[0]]);
$nuevo = [];
//Recorro el arreglo viejo para ir conformando el nuevo con la nueva estructura
array_walk($data, function($item, $key) use($keys, &$nuevo){
    //Recorro el arreglo donde estan los idiomas que van a ser mis llaves
    foreach($keys as $lang){
        //Agrego al arreglo nuevo la forma requerida
        $nuevo[$lang][$key] = $item[$lang];
    }
});

//Muestro el resultado
print_r($nuevo);
```

**ESTA SERIA LA SALIDA:**

```
Array
(
    [en] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title
            [description] => Description
        )

    [es] => Array
        (
            [title] => Titulo
            [description] => Descripcion
        )

 )
```